# Why does Thor keep saying this to Banner?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In **Thor Ragnarok** we have seen a couple of times when Thor keeps telling Banner "**the sun is down, the sun is down**" to calm him down and stop him from turning back to Hulk.

What is the reason behind Thor saying this to Hulk? I don't remember any reference from the previous MCU movies.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It relates to what Black Widow tells Hulk in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* in order to get him to come back to himself, to calm down and go back to being Bruce Banner.

From the question [What's that “Sun’s getting real low…” lullaby thing to calm down the Hulk?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39161/whats-that-sun-s-getting-real-low-lullaby-thing-to-calm-down-the-hulk)

> There is nothing specific about the words. They are just a trigger phrase/word to get Hulk's attention, like "en guard" or "Avengers Assemble". [Whedon said](http://herocomplex.latimes.com/movies/joss-whedon-talks-black-widows-painful-past-romantic-relationships-and-more/#/0):
>
> > **What about the words she says?**
> > ***“Hey there, big guy. The sun’s gettin’ real low.”*** *I actually added that later in the game, I think something basically to get his attention and to have a phrase that he knows, this is about to start.* I wanted to do as little with talking as possible, because it’s all going on there [points to his eyes], which is amazing, because two of those are not real — they were created by ILM, and yet they are so full of life. And I hate to say it, but he’s dead sexy as the Hulk.